# What is the best way to get the fullpath of an application that is not running?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the path of application "WinMergeU.exe" using `Path.GetFullPath()` but the return value of this code is the folder of my application.

How can i get the fullpath of the application in `C:` drive while the return value is `d` using the `Path.GetFullPath()`.

Comment: You have to find the file: `string result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "WinMergeU.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Do you know where `WinMergeU.exe" is placed?

Comment: @shingo. `C:\Program Files\WinMerge` this is the path sir

Comment: So the full path is `C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe`, just use it. I think you don't want to do full disk/driver scan to find the program.

Comment: but the system will be used in another computer sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed it, as it looked like a handy tool, and searched the registry.

```
string key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WinMerge.Project.File\shell\open\command";
string path = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(key, "", -1);
```

... seems to contain the value you need. In my case:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" "%1"`

The method will return -1 if the key is not found.

Comment: but sir the value i Need is `C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe`

Comment: throws an error sir `Registry key name must start with a valid base key name.`

Comment: @AlexisVillar Yeah, sorry, I just edited my answer. They key should not start with `computer\`. So I removed it from the key.

Comment: Yeah, try it like `path = path.Replace("\"", "").Replace(" %1", "");`

Answer (score 3):

You have to *search* for the file, e.g.

```
 using system.Linq;

 ...

 // Either full path of "WinMergeU.exe" file or null (if not found) 
 string result = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "WinMergeU.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit:** In case the application is in the `C:\Program Files` (see comments) we can restrict the scan:

```
  string result = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
                    "WinMergeU.exe",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or (if we quite sure in `c:\Program Files\WinMerge` path) we can just test if the file exits:

```
  string result = Path.Combine(
     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
    "WinMerge",
    "WinMergeU.exe");

  if (File.Exists(result)) {
    // we have the file
  }
```

Comment: `Access to the path 'c:\Documents and Settings' is denied.` It throwns an exception sir

Comment: @Alexis Villar: where do you want to look for the file? Is `"WinMergeU.exe"` on `c:` disk (i.e. `c:\WinMergeU.exe`) or somewhere in the *folder* (`c:\MyProgs\MyWorks\WinMergeU.exe`)?

Comment: Means you don't have the permissions needed to access that folder.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `C:\Program Files\WinMerge` This is the path of the Application sir

Comment: @DmitryBychenko. But when i Used this `"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe"` it has no problem sir. but the program should be the one who will get the path of this application.

how should i do that?

Comment: @Alexis Villar: let's scan not the entire `c:` drive, but `C:\Program Files` -  `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)`

Comment: still sir. it did not work. `Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\CrashReports' is denied.`. this throwns by debugger

Comment: @Alexis Villar: if you sure in the *subfolder* (i.e. `WinMergeU.exe` should be in `WinMerge` only) we can try build the path (`Path.Combine`) and check if the file exists.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko. I appreciate your kind hand for helping me sir. but still. it does not work. it has no exceptions but now it does not generate a txt file.

Comment: @Alexis Villar: sorry, but what text file? You want to run the `WinMergeU.exe` with some arguments?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: i am using that application path to run it using arguments sir.

Comment: Yes sir. just like that.

Comment: @Alexis Villar: OK, I see; let's complete the 1st stage: have you fiund the file (i.e. does `(File.Exists(result))` return `true` and `result` contains the expected path)? If yes, let's see how we should run the file.

Comment: Yes Sir. i found it.

Comment: but sir. the path returns by this line `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` is ProgramFilesx86 thats why it does not work. it only have an application but the files needed are missing

Comment: @Alexis Villar: it seems that you want to run 64-bit exe (`WinMergeU.exe`) from 32 bit one (your application). Is it possible for you to switch to 64-bit, e.g. in the project properties uncheck "Prefer 32-bit"?

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. I appreciate it :)\

Answer (score 1):

WinMerge doesn't allow to change its installation folder AFAIK, therefore searching the whole drive C is an overkill.

This will suffice:

```
static string GetWinMergeFullPath()
{
    const string executableName = "WinMergeU.exe";
    const string installationFolder = "WinMerge";
    var locations = new Environment.SpecialFolder[] 
    {
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles,
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86
    };

    string fullPath = locations
        .Select(l => Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(l), installationFolder, executableName))
        .Where(File.Exists)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return fullPath ?? throw new FileNotFoundException(executableName);
}
```

EDIT
As it was commented the above won't suffice:). The below version uses two registry locations that should contain the path. One is "App Paths" which is provided by the installation, the second one is "Uninstall". While I believe that "App Paths" should be enough I still provided the second one for robustness.Note that it will work even if shell integration is unchecked in the installer! Both 32-bit and 64-bit installations are covered.

```
static string GetWinMergeFullPathFromRegistryEx()
{
    const string executableName = "WinMergeU.exe";
    const string appPathKeyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\";
    const string uninstallKeyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WinMerge_is1";
    const string installLocationName = "InstallLocation";

    var locations = new List<(string path, string value, bool withFilename)>
    {
        ($"{appPathKeyName}{executableName}", null, true),
        (uninstallKeyName, installLocationName, false),
    };

    List<RegistryView> views = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ?
        new List<RegistryView>() { RegistryView.Registry32, RegistryView.Registry64 } :
        new List<RegistryView>() { RegistryView.Default };

    foreach (var view in views)
    {
        using (RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, view))
        foreach (var (path, value, withFilename) in locations)
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = localMachine.OpenSubKey(path, false))
            {
                var fullpathValue = key?.GetValue(value);
                if (fullpathValue != null)
                {
                    string fullpath = (string)fullpathValue;
                    if (!withFilename)
                        fullpath = Path.Combine(fullpath, executableName);
                    if (File.Exists(fullpath))
                        return fullpath;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    throw new FileNotFoundException(executableName);
}
```

Of course my assumption is that WinMerge was actually installed. If you should support cases when WinMerge was deployed manually then you still can use to the full scan option as a fallback.

Comment: It does let me assign a destination folder during installation. So you can't be sure the installation will be in one of the folders you mention.